# How to get all the methods of a subclass?

Tags: php, oop, class, object

I'm programming an object instance to other objects.
Now I need to validate an object instantiated.

The code i'm using is correct, but the objects are children of another object, so further back methods of parents.

**Code:**

```
<?php
class MyParentClass
{
    ...

    $objectName = "subClassExample";
    $obj = new $objectName();
    print_r( get_class_methods( $obj ) );

    ...
}
?>
```

**Return :**

```
Array ( [0] => __construct [1] => myMethod )
```

**The SubClass:**

```
<?php
class subClassExample extends parentClass
{

    public function myMethod()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
?>
```

**I need to return:**

```
Array ( [0] => myMethod )
```

The parent Class:

```
<?php
class parentClass
{

    function __construct ()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
?>
```

I hope I can help, I really appreciate it.
Greetings!

*P.S.: Excuse my English is not my language, I speak Spanish and Norwegian Bokmal.*

Comment: What is `$objectName`?  Which object is it?

Comment: $objectName is Object name... for example:
$objectName = 'subClassExample';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [PHP's Reflection<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php):

```
class Foo
{
    function foo() {}
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    function bar() {}
}

function get_class_methodsA($class)
{
    $rc = new ReflectionClass($class);
    $rm = $rc->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);

    $functions = array();
    foreach($rm as $f)
        $f->class === $class && $functions[] = $f->name;

    return $functions;
}

print_r(get_class_methodsA('Bar'));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => bar
)
```

Comment: excellent, thanks! it proved, but only with the documentation and see like me (:-})

Answer (score 0):

You may do this check inside a child or a parent class if you need only UNIQUE child's methods:

```
$cm = get_class_methods($this); //Get all child methods
$pm = get_class_methods(get_parent_class($this)); //Get all parent methods
$ad = array_diff($cm, $pm); //Get the diff
```

Keep in mind: `get_class_methods` returns all types of methods (public, protected etc.)